# Prolog Syntax Error : Operator expected

Tags: prolog

I have the error/solution `:5:10 :  Syntax Error : Operator expected`

```
nonoverlap(R,Task1,Task2) :-
   Task1 = task(_,T1,L1,Rs2),
   Task2 = task(_,T2,L2,Rs2),
   ((member(R,Rs1), member(R,Rs2)) ->
      T2 #> T1+L1     % start Task2 after Task1 has finished
       #\/             % OR
      T1 #> T2+L2     % start Task1 after Task2 has finished
   ;
      true            % non-conflicting, do nothing
   ).
```

Comment: You probably need to add `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).` at the start. CLP(FD) is not yet an autoloaded library in SWI.

Answer (score 2):

You need to say at the beginning of the file/module

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

And apart from that, you most probably want to say `T2 #>= T1 + L1`.

Also,  `abs(T2-T1) #>= min(L1,L2)` can be said, regardless of the order.